# Переключение раскладки клавиатуры Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: ubuntu

Доброго времени суток

Проблема в том, что бунта не хочет переключать раскладку сочетанием клавишь, как сделать?

(В 11.04 работало - поставил 11.10 - даже русской не было, руками добавлял, а теперь ещё и не меняется)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашёл сам (:

Главное меню - Раскладка клавиатуры - Параметры - Клавиши для смены раскладки - Отмечаете нужное.